# Image to content uri conversion issue in android

Tags: android, image, uri

I have getting Image as String URL

But i have to pass this image as in content uri format
Something like this:- content://media/external/images/media/35001
How to do this??

I need the image URI instead of url then only i can share the image to social medias like `twitter` , `facebook` etc.But i am getting the image as string url.So i can't share the image.
below given is the code:-

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        // continue with your code
        path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Title", null);
        image = Uri.parse(path);

        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("text/plain");
        share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I posted this text  " );
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, image);
        share.setType("image/jpeg");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to convert URL to URI:-

```
 String your_url = "http://example.com.au/Images/8e6c8e7b-7b97-494d-ac8b-27064841dfd3.jpg";
 URI uri = new URI(your_url.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.But its not working :(

Comment: okk can you explain little bit more that what you want to do...so that i can help you?